# How to use polymorphism to access derived class vector member from base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, polymorphism

It's said that with polymorphism, we can access a derived class member field with it's base class object like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Tool{
    public:
        Tool(){}
        Tool(string name){
            this->name = name;
        }
        virtual string getInfo(){
            return name;
        }
    //protected:
        string name;
};

class Computer: public Tool{
    public:
        Computer(string name, int price){
            this->name = name;
            this->price = price;
        }
        virtual string getInfo(){
            return name + ": " + to_string(static_cast<long long>(price));
        }
    //protected:
        int price;
};

class Person{
    public:
        Person(){}
        Person(string name){
            this->name = name;
        }
        virtual string getInfo(){
            return name;
        }
        virtual void addTools(Computer cmp){
            tools.push_back(cmp);
        }
    //protected:
        vector<Tool> tools;
        string name;
};

class Programmer: public Person{
    public:
        Programmer(string name, string job){
            this->name = name;
            this->job = job;
        }
        string getInfo(){
            return name + ": " + job;
        }
    //protected:
        string job;
};

int main(){
    Person prs("Person");
    Programmer prg("Daphloon", "programmer");

    Person* prs1 = &prs;
    Person* prs2 = &prg;

    cout << prs1->getInfo() << endl;    // result: Person
    cout << prs2->getInfo() << endl;    // result: Daphoon: programmer

    Tool tl("Hammer");
    Computer cmp("PC", 100);

    Tool* tl1 = &tl;
    Tool* tl2 = &cmp;


    cout << tl1->getInfo() << endl;     // result: Hammer
    cout << tl2->getInfo() << endl;     // result: PC: 100

    prs2->addTools(cmp);

    cout << prs2->tools[0].getInfo() << endl;   // result: PC
                                                // I expect the result will be: PC: 100 

    return 0;
}
```

The result wasn't what I expected. What I need is every derived class from `Person` have a vector `tools` that contains object that inherit from `Tool` class. If it described with word, it will be, "This `Person`, a `Programmer`, has some `tools`. His first `Tool` is a `Computer`. If you want to know what's  it's `price`, use `getInfo()`."

1. Why vector take the base class instead of the derived class?
2. Is there any data loss from `cmp` object when i put it inside `tools` vector?
3. Is this happen because `tools` vector member take `Tool` as it's type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Runtime polymorphism in C++, achieved via virtual functions, works on [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) types. The only covariant types are pointers and references. Since you have a `vector<Tool>`, you lose polymorphism. To retain it, store a `vector<Tool*>`. Even better, store a `vector<unique_ptr<Tool>>`.

Assigning a derived class object to a base class is called [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing#274636). You do lose information contained in the derived object. This is the case when you are inserting a `Computer` into a `vector<Tool>`.

Comment: Is that mean, when `Computer` object stored to `vector<Tool>` it become `Tool` Object? And `Computer` object lost it's `price` value?